# authorizeRequest oAuth not called from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm currently using **Oauth2SampleTouch** by Google, so people can log-in with their google accounts into my app. However whenever I call a method from The **SampleRootViewController** it doesn't go through the **authorizeRequest** method (only if I call it from another class.).

Here's the method in SampleRootViewController that I'm calling form another class.(the user is already logged in by this time)

```
-(NSString *)hasLikedVideo:(NSString *)videoID {

   liked = @"NULL";
    NSString *clientID = @"myClientID";
    NSString *clientSecret = @"myClientSecret";
    self.auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                      clientID:clientID
                                                                  clientSecret:clientSecret];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating?id=%@&key=AIzaSyB437bMtpbJh-OrkieCDRtYLe6L1Ijb3Ww", videoID];
    NSLog(@"URL FOR LIKE : %@ auth:(%@)", urlStr, self.auth);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"stage 1");


    [self.auth authorizeRequest:request
              completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                  if (error == nil) {
                      // the request has been authorized
                       NSLog(@"ERROR LOADING AUTH 1 : %@", [error description]);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"ERROR LOADING AUTH 2 : %@", [error description]);
                  }
                   NSLog(@"stage 2");
                  NSString *output = nil;
                  if (error) {
                      output = [error description];
                      NSLog(@"ERROR FROM LOADING LIKE INFO : %@", output);
                  } else {
                        NSLog(@"stage 3");
                      NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                      NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                           returningResponse:&response
                                                                       error:&error];

                      [self displayAlertWithMessage:output];
                      if (data) {
                          // API fetch succeeded
                          NSLog(@"stage 32");
                          output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                          // NSLog(@"%@", data);
                          [self displayAlertWithMessage:output];
                      } else {
                          NSLog(@"stage 34");
                          // fetch failed
                          output = [error description];
                          [self displayAlertWithMessage:output];
                      }
                  }


                  NSData* json = [output dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  NSDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization
                                              JSONObjectWithData:json
                                              options:kNilOptions
                                              error:&error];




                  NSArray *monday = allCourses[@"items"];
                  for ( NSDictionary *theCourse in monday )
                  {
                      liked = theCourse[@"rating"];
                      NSLog(@"LIKE INSIDE ARRAY : %@", theCourse[@"rating"]);

                  }



                  if( error )
                  {
                      NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                  }

              }];



    NSLog(@"stage 4");
    return liked;
}
```

The method runs because I can see it log the string, however it doesn't go through the **authorizeRequest**, it doesn't even print out the error messages. HOWEVER if my viewController is **SampleRootViewController** and I call the method from itself it works.

So basically

**TestViewcontroller** calls a method in **SampleRootViewController** -> doesn't go through **authorizeRequest**.

**SampleRootViewController** calls a method in **SampleRootViewController** (from itself) -> goes through **authorizeRequest** and works.

**EDIT:**

I found out what I was doing "wrong"

I was calling the method like this in background

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getAuthDetails) withObject:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self getAuthDetails];
```

Comment: Check to see if the SampleRootViewController is being deallocated (implement dealloc and put a log in it) when you call the method from TestViewController.

Comment: Nothing gets called inside dealloc in SampleRootViewController

Comment: Which logs do you see? Do you see the one that logs "stage 4"?

Comment: I see stage 1 and stage 4 being called.

Comment: When you call the method from TestViewController, how do you create an instance of SampleRootViewController, or is it already in existence?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll make an edit to show how I call the method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53868/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jessica)